# Solve matrix differential equation around known solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-exponential

Define a matrix differential equation $\dot{X}=A(t)X(t)$ with initial condition $X(0)$, where $X=[x_1,x_2,\ldots]^T$ is a 1D vector and $A(t)$ is a complex-valued time-dependent matrix.

This system can be solved by $X(t)= \mathcal{T}{\rm exp}(\int_0^t A(t')dt') X(0)$, where we introduce a time-ordered exponential. In general, this is an arduous task. For my specific case, I know how to solve a similar, but simpler limit.

Assume $A(t)=A_s+A_I(t)$, then $\dot{X}=(A_s+A_I(t))X(t)$.

For the time-independent part, I know the answer $X_{s}(t)=e^{A_0 t}X(0)$.

Given these conditions, and knowing that the effect $A_I(t)$ has on the system is small, i.e. the new solution shouldn't be too much different from $X_{s}(t)$, is there anything I can do? Any approximation?

I am expecting I could do some transformation of the sort $X(t)=U(t)X_s(t)$, with $U(t)=U(t,A_I)$. Given the time-ordered exponential, is there any perturbation that would give me this transformation?

Comment: What you want to do is analogous (in fact, identical) to the [interaction picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture) of quantum mechanics. The linked article may help you.

Comment: I am familiar with the interaction picture, but I do not see your point. Where would I incorporate information about the known solution $X_s(t)$?

Comment: See my answer. ${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort of transformation you are looking for is given by
$$
U(t):=e^{A_st}U_I(t)e^{-A_st}, \tag{1}
$$
where $U_I(t)$ is the solution to the IVP
\begin{align}
\dot{U_I}(t)&=e^{-A_st}A_I(t)e^{A_st}U_I(t), \tag{2} \\
U_I(0)&=\mathbb{1}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
To prove this, we have to show that
$$
X(t)=U(t)X_s(t)=U(t)e^{A_st}X_0 \tag{4}
$$
satisfies the differential equation
$$
\dot{X}(t)=(A_s+A_I(t))X(t) \tag{5}
$$
with initial condition $X(0)=X_0$. Let's begin with the latter:
$$
X(t)=U(t)X_s(t)\overset{(1,4)}{=}e^{A_st}U_I(t)e^{-A_st}e^{A_st}X_0=e^{A_st}U_I(t)X_0 \tag{6}
$$
$$
\implies X(0)=U_I(0)X_0\overset{(3)}=X_0. \tag{7}
$$
Now let's show that (4) satisfies $(5)$:
\begin{align}
\dot{X}(t)&\overset{(6)}{=}A_se^{A_st}U_I(t)X_0+e^{A_st}\dot{U_I}(t)X_0 \\
&\overset{(2)}{=}A_sX(t)+e^{A_st}e^{-A_st}A_I(t)e^{A_st}U_I(t)X_0 \\
&\overset{(6)}{=}A_sX(t)+A_I(t)X(t). \quad{\square} \tag{8}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I will work on it, thanks! :)